# Load big xml file in sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, c#-4.0

I have to load a very large xml file in sql server 2008 r2. 
The file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<listaCupons xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cupomVenda>
        <codFilial>123456</codFilial>
        <dtVenda>2013-01-01T00:00:00</dtVenda>
        <numeroDePdv>0.000000000000000</numeroDePdv>
        <cupomFiscal>12345</cupomFiscal>
        <horaVenda xsi:nil="true"/>
        <tipoVenda>1</tipoVenda>
        <vendedorVip>FUlano de tal</vendedorVip>
        <cpfCnpjAdquirente xsi:nil="true"/>
        <item>
            <numeroDoItem>1</numeroDoItem>
            <codigoDoProduto>2134</codigoDoProduto>
            <qtde>1</qtde>
            <valorUnitario>399.000</valorUnitario>
            <ultimoCusto>216.150</ultimoCusto>
        </item>
    </cupomVenda>
</listaCupons>
```

I have the following table structure:

```
Table CupomVenda
idCupomVenda int auto increment
codFilial int
dtVenda date
numeroDePdv varchar (20)
cupomFiscal int
horaVenda smallint
tipoVenda bit
vendedorVip varchar(80)
cpfCnpjAdquirente char(14)

Table ItemCupomVenda (child from CupomVenda)

idItemCupomVenda int auto Increment
numeroDoItem int
codigoDoProduto int
qtde int
valorUnitario float
ultimoCusto float
idCupomVenda int (relation with primary key from CupomVenda)
```

I accept any solution, since i have to use it in .net. I found some examples that uses sqlbulkcopy class, but i thing i can't use it with a xmlReader class, which i guess is the right one for this case.

Comment: In what kind of table structure are you going to store it?

Comment: Have you looked at the [SQLXMLBulkLoad object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171993.aspx)? There are specific instructions for using it with .NET [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171878.aspx).

Comment: Table cupomVenda, field idCupomVenda (auto increment) plus the same fields in xml, in respective order of type: int, int, date, varchar(20), int, smallint, bit, varchar(80), char(14).

And also I will store in Item table, with IdItemCupomVenda (auto increment), plus the field types in same order as fields in xml: int, int, int, float, float. Plus idCupomVenda (int), to make the relationship between them both. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EduardoLion Please edit your question to add this information; it's very difficult to read important details from the comments.

Comment: do you want to store the xml contents in your db OR do you want to shred and store the values into the database in relational tables?

Comment: @granadaCoder I prefer to use the table structure i have, but if it isn't possible, i'm ok with any other solution. The only requisites is to store in our sql server, and to use .net.

Comment: @Pondlife it is edited!

Comment: Don't forget a "this helped" Upvote (if you felt any answers were helpful) and even the "mark as correct answer" possibility.

Comment: the system don't let me vote up, it says i need to have 15 points of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

This query should get you off the ground.

The key is to shred your Xml.  But since you're inserting into a table with an IDENTITY, you have to use "natural keys" to get back at the "surrogate IDENTITY key".

So as long as your "codFilial" (that I call the "codFilialNaturalKey") is a unique constraint, you'll be able to piggy back off of that to match up the PK of the parent table to the FK of the child table.

I did a few of the columns of data for you (which also means I didn't do every column for you).  And added extra "item" elements so show that it works for multiple "item"'s.

There is a DataSet DateTime converter (UDF) also listed.  You'll want to pull your value as a varchar and THEN run it through the UDF to convert to a DateTime.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationCupomVendaParentTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationCupomVendaParentTable
end



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable
end


CREATE TABLE #DestinationCupomVendaParentTable
(
CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKey int not null identity (1001, 1), 
codFilialNaturalKey int, 
tipoVenda int
)



CREATE TABLE #DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable
(
DestinationChildSurrogateIdentityKey int not null identity (3001, 1), 
CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK int, 
numeroDoItemNaturalKey int,
codigoDoProduto int
)





-- Declare XML variable

DECLARE @data XML;

-- Element-centered XML

SET @data = N'
<listaCupons xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cupomVenda>
        <codFilial>123456</codFilial>
        <dtVenda>2013-01-01T00:00:00</dtVenda>
        <numeroDePdv>0.000000000000000</numeroDePdv>
        <cupomFiscal>12345</cupomFiscal>
        <horaVenda xsi:nil="true"/>
        <tipoVenda>1</tipoVenda>
        <vendedorVip>FUlano de tal</vendedorVip>
        <cpfCnpjAdquirente xsi:nil="true"/>
        <item>
            <numeroDoItem>9001</numeroDoItem>
            <codigoDoProduto>2134</codigoDoProduto>
            <qtde>1</qtde>
            <valorUnitario>399.000</valorUnitario>
            <ultimoCusto>216.150</ultimoCusto>
        </item>

        <item>
            <numeroDoItem>9002</numeroDoItem>
            <codigoDoProduto>32134</codigoDoProduto>
            <qtde>1</qtde>
            <valorUnitario>399.000</valorUnitario>
            <ultimoCusto>216.150</ultimoCusto>
        </item>
    </cupomVenda>


    <cupomVenda>
        <codFilial>234567</codFilial>
        <dtVenda>2013-01-01T00:00:00</dtVenda>
        <numeroDePdv>0.000000000000000</numeroDePdv>
        <cupomFiscal>23456</cupomFiscal>
        <horaVenda xsi:nil="true"/>
        <tipoVenda>4</tipoVenda>
        <vendedorVip>FUlano de tal</vendedorVip>
        <cpfCnpjAdquirente xsi:nil="true"/>
        <item>
            <numeroDoItem>9011</numeroDoItem>
            <codigoDoProduto>3256</codigoDoProduto>
            <qtde>4</qtde>
            <valorUnitario>333.44</valorUnitario>
            <ultimoCusto>333.55</ultimoCusto>
        </item>

        <item>
            <numeroDoItem>9013</numeroDoItem>
            <codigoDoProduto>33256</codigoDoProduto>
            <qtde>4</qtde>
            <valorUnitario>333.44</valorUnitario>
            <ultimoCusto>333.55</ultimoCusto>
        </item>
    </cupomVenda>


</listaCupons>

';




INSERT INTO #DestinationCupomVendaParentTable ( codFilialNaturalKey ,  tipoVenda )
SELECT T.parentEntity.value('(codFilial)[1]', 'INT') AS codFilial,
       T.parentEntity.value('(tipoVenda)[1]', 'INT') AS tipoVenda
FROM @data.nodes('listaCupons/cupomVenda') AS T(parentEntity)
/* add a where not exists check on the natural key */
where not exists (
    select null from #DestinationCupomVendaParentTable innerRealTable where innerRealTable.codFilialNaturalKey = T.parentEntity.value('(codFilial)[1]', 'INT') )
;

/* Optional.  You could do a UPDATE here based on matching the #DestinationCupomVendaParentTablecodFilialNaturalKey = T.parentEntity.value('(codFilial)[1]', 'INT')
You could Combine INSERT and UPDATE using the MERGE function on 2008 or later.
 */



INSERT INTO #DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable (  CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK ,  numeroDoItemNaturalKey , codigoDoProduto )
SELECT  par.CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKey , 
        T.childEntity.value('(numeroDoItem)[1]', 'INT') AS numeroDoItem,
        T.childEntity.value('(codigoDoProduto)[1]', 'INT') AS codigoDoProduto
FROM @data.nodes('listaCupons/cupomVenda/item') AS T(childEntity)
/* The next join is the "trick".  Join on the natural key (codFilial)....**BUT** insert the CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKey into the table */
join #DestinationCupomVendaParentTable par on par.codFilialNaturalKey = T.childEntity.value('(../codFilial)[1]', 'INT')
where not exists (
    select null from #DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable innerRealTable where innerRealTable.CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK = par.CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKey AND  innerRealTable.numeroDoItemNaturalKey = T.childEntity.value('(numeroDoItem)[1]', 'INT'))
;



print '/#DestinationCupomVendaParentTable/'
select * from #DestinationCupomVendaParentTable


print '/#DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable/'
select * from #DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable


select codFilialNaturalKey , tipoVenda , numeroDoItemNaturalKey , codigoDoProduto , par.CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKey as ParentPK , child.CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK as childFK from #DestinationCupomVendaParentTable par join #DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable child
on par.CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKey = child.CupomVendaParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationCupomVendaParentTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationCupomVendaParentTable
end


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationItemCupomVendaChildTable
end
```

Here is a UDF to convert a DataSet DateTime to a SqlServer value:

```
if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id('udfConvertXmlDateToTsqlDate') and xtype = 'FN')
    drop function udfConvertXmlDateToTsqlDate
GO


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfConvertXmlDateToTsqlDate (@input_xml_date varchar(64))

/*


Original Need : When adding a value to a DataSet/datetime column,
                the DataSet stores the date as an xml formatted date
                TSQL does not like xml formatted dates
                This procedure will transfer a xml formatted date,
                into a datetime tsql datatype.
Sample Usage :

        select dbo.udfConvertXmlDateToTsqlDate ('2002-06-20T00:00:00.0000000+05:30') as myConvertedDate
        will yield:
            myConvertedDate                                        
            ------------------------------------------------------ 
            2002-06-20 00:00:00.000


        DateTime.MinValue Test

        select dbo.udfConvertXmlDateToTsqlDate ('0001-01-01T00:00:00-05:00') as myConvertedDate



Notes : 
            The procedure strips out the time part of the datetime.

*/


RETURNS 


datetime

AS
BEGIN


        --This is a DotNet/Xml/DataSet and DateTime.MinValue work around
        if LEFT(@input_xml_date,16)  = '0001-01-01T00:00' --  :00-05:00'
            BEGIN
                return null 
            END



    RETURN 

        --CONVERT(datetime , LEFT(@input_xml_date , (CHARINDEX('T', @input_xml_date))-1))
        CONVERT(datetime , LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), @input_xml_date, 126), 10))

        -- SEE "Data Type Coercions" (SQL Server 2000 Books Online)
        -- this has the code above as the translation mechanism
        -- for converted an xml formatted datestamp into a TSQL datetime

END
GO


GRANT REFERENCES ON udfConvertXmlDateToTsqlDate TO public


GO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @granadaCoder! I think it's exactly what i need, i just have one more doubt: where you have `SET @data = N'`, how do i do to use the path of my xml file? cause they have really huge size, i can't open then to copy their text to the sql server.

Comment: I've never done it like that.  I put the above code in a stored procedure, and call the stored procedure from DotNet code.  Aka , my 'xml' was 'in memory', not a file sitting on a disk.  So you can either push your file into a holding table in sql server and read it from there, or file-stream read your file and push it down that way.  One more suggestion.. one row at a time is too little, your entire file may be too big, you may want to "chunk it"...here is a kinda demo : http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/bulk-insert-example-using-an-idatareader-to-strong-dataset-to-sql-server-xml/

Comment: "Very large" is relative.  I've done xml....that (if it were to be written to file on disk), would be about 4MB.  You just gotta try yours and see what happens.

Comment: Very large means 1 gb and more!

Comment: So if one record out of 1,000,000 isn't "correct", then what happens?  Do you want the 999,999 to "go" but log the errant one, or do you want the whole thing to fail?      If you want to log the occasional mishap, and "keep rolling", then I would follow the "chunk it up" example.  You'll have a way to prevalidate and/or massage any data, you can find the correct "batch size" (1000 in the example).....and tweak that number.     The logic I wrote for my real project was "try 1,000 at a time, if that fails, then go over them one by one and log the errant ones"........that way..

Comment: you are normally inserting 1000 at a time (faster), but you have an "safety value" for those occasional errant rows.    I'm also assuming this is a process you're repeating, not just a one-time deal.

Comment: i can't even open the file to split it. Your code works fine when i put the text itself of xml in the function, i can't open it to split it in N small files.

Comment: I don't really know then.  If your data in the DOM isn't disjoint, you may have to put a XmlReader (forward only reader) on your big xml.